# How to properly define the number of threads for jobs spanning multiple nodes?

Tags: slurm, snakemake

I have a snakemake pipeline running on an hpc cluster using slurm as batch system. In principle, the pipeline is running fine, but I experience problems when a job submitted by snakemake spans multiple nodes. In that case not all allocated CPUs are counted towards the `{threads}` parameter, but only those that are allocated on one node, disregarding the others. `squeue` on the other hand indicates, that the correct number of cores is requested. Is the `{threads}` parameter really to be used only in the context of actual threads on a shared memory machine, or can I somehow tell snakemake to understand it more in the sense of available cores?

For the sake of an example, if I have a pipeline like this:

`pipeline.skmk`:

```python
CLUSTER = json.load(open("cluster.json"))

rule sleep_test:
    output:
        "something_{number}"
    threads: CLUSTER['sleep_test']['n']
    log:
        "logs/something_{number}"
    shell:
        """
        echo {output} > {log} && sleep 20 && echo {threads} > {output}
        """

rule gather:
    input:
        expand("something_{number}", number=[0, 1, 2, 3])
    output:
        "done.txt"
    shell:
        """
        touch {output}
        """
```

`cluster.json`:

```json
{
    "__default__" :
    {
        "time" : "00:01:00",
        "n" : 1,
        "mem": "3G",
        "output" : "logs/slurm/{rule}.{wildcards}.%j.out",
        "error" : "logs/slurm/{rule}.{wildcards}.%j.err"
    },
    "sleep_test" :
    {
        "time" : "00:02:00",
        "n" : 20,
        "mem": "3G",
        "output" : "logs/slurm/{rule}.{wildcards}.%j.out",
        "error" : "logs/slurm/{rule}.{wildcards}.%j.err"
    }
}
```

Command:

```
snakemake --snakefile pipeline.skmk --printshellcmds \
    --directory "test" --cluster-config cluster.json --jobname "test.{jobid}" \
    --cluster-status slurm_status.py \
    --cluster "sbatch --parsable -n {cluster.n} -t {cluster.time} \
               --error {cluster.error} --output {cluster.output}" \
    done.txt
```

If I now run this on a machine with 3 nodes and 30 cores each, one job will be split to use 10 cores of two different nodes. This is fine with me, as the communication between the cores is handled in a way not requiring shared memory. But in this case, the `{threads}` parameter that is passed to the shell command will be 10, not 20 (as one can see in the output files). To make things weirder, the shell command printed by snakemake says 20 in all cases. As does the snakemake log. Only the jobs logfiles and the output show `threads` as 10. Do I do something wrong here? Is there a way to tell snakemake to use all available cores of a job or is the `{threads}` parameter only to be used for threads on a shared memory machine?